# Insert thousands of records one by one

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

Edited...

Probably I wasn't clear in my original post. I only process the File name.

The file name already contains all the information I want.
Eg. `2011--8-27_13:20:45_MyLocation_User1.jpg`.

I decode the name and insert into the table with columns (DateTime, Location, User).
I'm not opening the file. It's a Jpg image. After processing it, I need move the file to a folder based on the UserName.

Now I'm using Insert Statement

```
 Private Function InsertToDB(ByVal SourceFile As String, ByVal Date_Time As DateTime, ByVal Loc As String, ByVal User As String) As Boolean

    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConString)
    Dim sSQL As String = "INSERT INTO StageTbl ...."
    Dim cmd As SqlComman
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sSQL, conn)

    ....Parameters Set ...

      conn.Open()
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      conn.Close()
      conn = Nothing
      cmd = Nothing
    End Function
```

The function will be called for every single file found.

Is this most efficient way? Looks like it's is very slow. I need to process about 20~50 files/sec. Probably a stored procedure?

I need to do this as fast as possible. I guess bulk insert not applicable here.

Please help.

Comment: You should definitely look at bulk insert (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

Comment: Agreed with Kshitij Mehta. Using a data table and a bulk insert will by far be the most efficient way that you can achieve this.

Comment: Veylan, don't forget to mark the correct answer.  That's how this place works and welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: @griegs, while I agree we should encourage users to up-vote and accept answers, what is the rush in this case? The question is only half an hour old. Give some other people a chance to submit an answer too. The first answer isn't necessarily the only good answer the OP will get...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)?

Also, look into processing in batches. You can insert multiple rows in SQL Server using row constructors.

```
INSERT INTO <table> (Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES (File1, Val2, Val3),
       (File2, Val2, Val3),
       (File3, Val2, Val3)
```

Comment: With a limitiation (in SQL server 2008b) of 1000 rows, i'd like to add

Answer (score 0):

As far SQL is concerned;

1. Get your indexes right
2. Use a Transaction and commit it at the end.

As for moving files;

You don't say how big the files are.  If they are small then as you process them you could move them.

If they're big then perhaps deal with them later.  You could use MSMQ I guess to move the file when there is time or processor time.

You'd need to keep a log of the processed ones but that's no real issue

**edit**

create a workflow using WWF and create a WF for each file to process.  Then the workflow can take care of things like SQL insert, moving and placing file into an error folder if there is one.

.Net can automatically monitor a folder for new files and kick off a process.

Comment: Prob I wasn't clear. I only process the File name.

The file name is already contains all the information I want.
Eg. 2011--8-27_13:20:45_MyLocation_User1.jpg.
I decode the name and insert into the table with columns (DateTime, Location, User).

I'm not opening the file. After I move the file to a diff folder

Now I'm using Insert Statement
conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
conn = Nothing
cmd = Nothing
Is this efficient? Looks very slow. Need to process 20~50 files/sec. StoreProc fast?

I need to do this as fast as possible. I guess bulk insert not applicable here.

Please help.